# Log4j seems to be skipping log entries for one, specific package-- despite configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I added a bunch of logging to a specific class that's been giving me troubles, ramped up the **log4j.properties** file and expected to see a ton of debugging information.

While I **do** see more info the messages from one, specific class-- the one I was most interested in-- seems to be completely missing.

Oddly enough, I copied **log4j.properties** file from the test server-- where it was, indeed, outputting the right info-- over to the production server-- they're identical.

Here's the contents of the **log4j.properties**:

```
log4j.debug=false

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, S

log4j.category.com.communitect=DEBUG, F1, S
log4j.additivity.com.communitect=false

log4j.appender.F1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.F1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.F1.File=${catalina.base}/logs/smilereminder_log
log4j.appender.F1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%c{2}) - %m%n

log4j.appender.S=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

That file is in the **lib** directory of my Tomcat install.

The package I see **nothing** from is this:

```
package com.communitect.business;
```

The way I declare the logger is this:

```
static private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( PersonalReminderRules.class );
```

All of the messages from this class show up on my test server so I know the **log4j.properties** file *should* work great.

I looked around for an additional **log4j.properties** file but there doesn't seem to be one.  There isn't an **.xml** configuration file, either.

Something's eluding me.  Any ideas?

Comment: If Test and Production have the same log4j.properties (and neither has a log4j.xml file), the difference should be in the code. Maybe there are some kind of "DEBUG_MODE" flags in the code?

Comment: Stupid question but the `PersonalReminderRules.class` argument is correct, right?  It isn't a cut-and-paste error right?  Are you sure that there isn't a `log4j.properties` file hiding in your classpath?

Comment: How are you telling your stuff about the log4j.properties file?  Using the log4j.configuration system property or just depending on the classpath?  I like to use the system property so that I know exactly where it's getting the config from.  I'm betting the problem is either that you're not using the config file you think you are, or that your logging additions are not in the code on your production server.

Comment: I think I may have found something.  Appending the error I saw to the question!

Comment: So it appears that the **appVoice** WebApp context had a log4j.jar in it.  Removing it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: From the classloader's error, I'd think that information about server and loading methods could be relevant. Specially anything that's different from test server.

Comment: Can you please add the solution as an answer rather than as an edit to your question?  You can then select yours as the correct answer and close out your question. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Comment: @amy_half you should post your solution as a real answer (which you can accept later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@oers, good idea, thank you!  :)

Here was the solution we found:

So it appears that the **appVoice** WebApp context had a **log4j.jar** in it. Removing it seems to have fixed the problem.

I'm assuming that classloading the webapps "overrode" the classes loaded originally and consequently with a brand new configuration.